# featurewise std normalization can not fit for each batch in flow from directory

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to normalize and standardize the images of each batch from Dataset.
The formula is: Xi = (Xi - mean) / std (pixel-level global mean (SD))

I use ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory as below:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True, 
                             featurewise_std_normalization=True, 
                             vertical_flip=True,              #data augmentation 
                             validation_split= 0.1,           #validation
                             rescale=1./255,                  #Scaling
                             horizontal_flip=True)            #data augmentation 

train_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_data_dir,
            target_size=(img_height,img_width),
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_mode='binary',
            subset='training',
            shuffle=True)

valid_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(...)

model = Model(...) #I use ResNet and some fully connected layer
model.compile(...)

trainer= model.fit(train_gen,
                   validation_data= valid_gen,
                   epochs=16,
                   verbose=2)
```

As what I need, I use `featurewise_center` and `featurewise_std_normalization` in `ImageDataGenerator`. but it seems that these options do NOT work with `flow_from_directory` ! also I should use `flow_from_directory` because my data is heavy (I don't have enough RAM for processing whole the dataset at the same time).

Can you give me some recommendations or advice for solving this problem,. i.e how to implement pixel-level global mean (SD) for pictures in this method?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the effect you must run `train_generator.fit` before you train your model. Documentation for this is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)